# How do you access javascript from selenium and submit a form?

Tags: perl, selenium

I have some html that uses JS to submit a form:

```
<form onsubmit="doform();return false;">
```

In the test script I'm doing the following based on what I found here on SO and in 
the WWW::Selenium docs.

```
$sel->get_eval("this.browserbot.getUserWindow().doform()");
```

The normal form submission works fine but it does not work in the selenium code.

If I scoop the JS out of the js file and make a string in the test file it works fine.

```
my $js = "{ //do some javascript stuff here; }";
$sel->get_eval( $js );                              // this works.
```

I'm under the impression that that is not the correct way to do that though. It's certainly 
not desirable, especially when the function calls other functions.

What is the correct form for using selenium to submit a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method to submit the form (which should also fire the onsubmit javascript).

From [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.32/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm):

```
$sel->submit($form_locator)
```

Will submit the specified form. $form_locator is an element locator for the form you want to submit.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This is correct and was in fact what I was doing. I was working on two different tests at the same time and confused them.  In the case of the form the error happened after the submission. The actual problem I'm having is half of what it is here for which I'll start a new question I guess.